# Django Model.Objects.order_by charField which can contain notes written in different languages(ENG, RUS)

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

`name` can be written in two languages: English and Russian. When i use `A.objects.order_by('-name')`, English words stand before Russian. How can i swap it?

Comment: English chars are higher in the UTF table than the others so you'll have to do it manually. http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Answer (score 0):

This was asked almost three years ago, but if you would like to swap the order, you could simply do:

```py
query = A.objects.order_by("name")
```

Django changes the order by ascending and descending based on the presence of a `-` symbol before the field name.